# Using Scrapy-splash to navigate dynamic pages

Tags: javascript, selenium, dynamic, web-crawler, scrapy-splash

**Background:** I am using Scrapy to crawl and scrape product data from `http://shop.nordstrom.com/c/mens-tshirts`. The page is dynamically generated so I use Scrapy-Splash to deal with the JavaScript. The problem is, clicking the "Next" button on the bottom of the page is the only way to get to the subsequent product page. If you copy that url of page 2 and paste it into a new tab, the page has no products on it.

In order to combat this, I am trying to use the `.click()` function in Selenium to navigate to the next page, and `driver.page_source` to extract the html of the page.

**Question:** Is there a way to pass the html/javascript source that I extract into Splash (running inside a docker container), rather than passing in a url? I've tried saving the html on my local machine and passing the file path, but that results in a 502 Bad Gateway because Splash automatically prepends 'http://' to the path.

Maybe there's a better method for achieving my goal here, if so I'm open to any options. Please keep in mind that the solution must be appropriate for **scalability and cloud deployment**. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can write a Splash Lua script which calls [splash:set_content](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html#splash-set-content) instead of accepting an URL, something like this:

```
function main(splash, args)
    assert(splash:set_content(args.html_source))
    -- page is loaded, process it as needed
end
```

You can also click on a button in Splash itself - see [element:mouse_click](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-element-object.html#splash-element-mouse-click), something like this:

```
function main(splash, args)
    assert(splash:go(args.url))
    splash:select('.next'):mouse_click()
    splash:wait(5.0) 
    return splash:html()
end
```

Check the [tutorial](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-tutorial.html) and [Lua API overview](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-overview.html) for more. You can interact with the page like in Selenium; not all Selenium helpers are available, but basics are there.

Comment: I am using Scrapy to do the actual scraping, is there a way to then pass that html to Scrapy (in lieu of a url). Usually I'd just call Scrapy on the `RENDER_HTML_URL` where Splash renders the JS (in a local Docker container), though if I can avoid running the container locally, that would be very preferred.
Also, does the second Lua script actually render the JS? That is my whole reason for using Splash in the first place.

Comment: You can pass HTML from Splash to Scrapy and process it at Scrapy side - call "return splash:html" (check the linked tutorial). But I'm not sure why you need this in the first example, as Selenum also processes JS. Yes, second Lua script renders JS, Splash does that by default.